# WebApi: verification of json signing

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I am working on and Web API in ASP.NET MVC4 using ApiController classes. The API will have authentication checks based on signature verification. Every request has to be signed using POST body and some secret key.

I also want to use Model binding from JSON to objects.

And now I have a problem. I can send JSON and .net binds it nicely to objects, but I can't get verification to work.

How can I get POST content (in exact form in was sent) when Contenttype of POST is application/json?

Example

POST content (application/json):

```
{message: "blah"}
```

Model class:

```
public class RequestModel
{
    public String Message { get; set; }
}
```

How to get the JSON in the ApiController?

Comment: where you are writing verification logic ?

Comment: Using ActionFilterAttribute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read the request body as string using `request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();`. However, this will not work in the action method or a filter.

In the ASP.NET Web API pipeline, model binding happens before the action filter runs and then action method executes. Model binder would have read the request body (which is a read-once stream) and emptied the contents. Instead, if you read the content from a component running before the model binding, say a message handler, you can read the request body (JSON, in your case).

```
public class MyHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
                                HttpRequestMessage request,
                                    CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var messageBody = await request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        return await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

Here, messageBody will have the JSON. It is better to implement the checking here because handler runs earlier in the pipeline and you will want to enforce authentication as early as possible.

Comment: I have found that if you consume the stream (ReadyAsStreamAsync) the model binding will fail as it continues to read the stream from where you left it. You must set the stream position back to zero once you have extracted the messageBody.

Answer (score 0):

just pay attention, your json message should be exactly equal to your model. (Message property not message)

post:

```
{Message: "blah"}
```

Model class:

```
public class RequestModel
{
    public String Message { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
[System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
public RequestModel PostUser(RequestModel model)
{
  //code
}
```

Comment: Yes, this part works as expected, but I need String form of the JSON posted in exact form like it was sent (with whitespaces etc). It's needed to create hash of the request and compare with the one created on client

Comment: Sorry. Could you use NewtonSoft (Json library)? http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx

Comment: No, I need JSON in exact form it was sent by client

Answer (score 0):

Read exact body from Request is not enough? :)

```
Request.InputStream // <--
```

Answer (score 0):

In similar vein to @Badri's answer above, when you use ReadAsStreamAsync() you must return the "read head" of the stream to zero, else the model binding will fail as the stream has already been consumed

```
public class MyHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
                                HttpRequestMessage request,
                                CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        using(var sha = System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256.Create())
        {
            var requestStream = await request.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
            var shaHash = sha.ComputeHash(requestStream);
            requestStream.Position = 0; // <-Important!!
        }


        return await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```